# 64 bit VM does not start pointer compression, resulting in -8 memory alignment

Tags: java

maven pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjdk.jol</groupId>
    <artifactId>jol-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Java class:

```java
public class MyObjectData {

    private  int i=66;
    private  long l=6L;
    private String string=new String("aaaa");

}

public class ObjectTest {

    @Test
    public  void test1() {
        Layouter l;
        //64 bit vm object distribution, pointer compression not enabled
        l = new HotSpotLayouter(new X86_64_DataModel());
        System.out.println("***** " + l);
        System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseInstance(new MyObjectData(),l).toPrintable());
        System.out.println("==============================================");
    }

}
```

Running results：

```
OFFSET  SIZE               TYPE DESCRIPTION                               VALUE
      0     4                    (object header)                           01 00 00 00 (00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000) (1)
      4     4                    (object header)                           00 00 00 00 (00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000) (0)
      8     4                    (object header)                           01 23 01 f8 (00000001 00100011 00000001 11111000) (-134143231)
     12     4                    (object header)                           42 00 00 00 (01000010 00000000 00000000 00000000) (66)
     16     8               long MyObjectData.l                            6
     24     4                int MyObjectData.i                            66
     28     4                    (alignment/padding gap)
     32     8   java.lang.String MyObjectData.string                       (object)
     40    -8                    (loss due to the next object alignment)
Instance size: 32 bytes
Space losses: 4 bytes internal + -8 bytes external = -4 bytes total`
```

I don't understand why the 64 bit VM did not start pointer compression when checking the memory usage of the object, resulting in -8 memory alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand why the 64 bit VM did not start pointer compression when checking the memory usage of the object ...

The JVM doesn't dynamically start pointer compression; e.g. *"... did not **start** pointer compression **when checking the memory usage of the object**..."*

Rather, it decides whether or not to use compressed oops when the (64 bit) JVM starts.  It decides based on the command line options; i.e. `UseCompressedOops`, `ObjectAlignmentInBytes` and the maximum heap size.  The maximum heap size is either given by `-xmx` or determined by a platform-specific default algorithm.

So ... you would need to look at the (actual and default) JVM options for your JVM to figure out why compressed oops are (apparently) not in effect.  Use `-XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags` to find out.